# Linq group by and order by sum

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I simply want to do this SQL in Linq. But how?

```
Select Id, sum(Count) 
from dbo.BThread 
group by Id 
order by sum(Count) desc
```

I tried this and its fails: the result gives only one row. I expect a lot more rows than this. There is many ids that I need to sum count on.

```
var List = (from tbBThread in context.BThread.Take(10)
                group tbBThread by tbBThread.Id into bTmp
                orderby bTmp.Sum(x => x.Count)
                select new BViewModel
                {
                    Id = bTmp.Key,
                    Id = bTmp.First().Id,
                    Count = bTmp.Sum(x => x.Count)
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: remove the second `Id = bTmp.First().Id,`

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is because you just mention that it fails without any details on what fails (Hint: add more details to the question), but you can't have 2 `Id` in the select

Comment: The result gives only one row. I expect a lot more rows than this. There is many id’s that I need to sum count on.

Comment: the `.Id` needs to be a comparable type like `int` or `string`. What is the type of `.Id` ?

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I did clean the example, but a bit to much. The Id is a profile id. I have a table, where the profile id is a foreign key. I that table there is a count of each row. I want to group the total count for each profile id. Then return id profile id and count.

Comment: The next step is to list it for top 10 rows ordering desc by count

Comment: The id type is int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Take(10)` should be at the end of your query.

```
var List = (from tbBThread in context.BThread
            group tbBThread by tbBThread.Id into bTmp
            orderby bTmp.Sum(x => x.Count)
            select new BViewModel
            {
                Id = bTmp.Key,
                Count = bTmp.Sum(x => x.Count)
            }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Otherwise you only look at the first 10 elements of your `context.BThread` which seem to have the same `Id` and thus go into the same group.

And (as Slai already said in the comments) remove the second `Id = bTmp.First().Id,`.

Comment: When I use orderby and sum I get a warning that "The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally."

Comment: Does this ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/53730334 ) or this ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-9-and-entity-framework-6-3-preview-9/) help you?